# What gear does Robbie Lawrence use?

Tags: equipment-identification, photographer

I’m wondering if someone could recognize which kind of camera [Robbie Lawrence](http://robbie-lawrence.com/) uses.

I think his image could have been shot with an analogue camera, but I’m not really sure because a lot of people use digital cameras and recreate the analog touch in post production.

Comment: Did you try contacting the photographer? There's an email address on the website you linked to.

Comment: With just a basic perusal of the linked site, I don't think that it's as much about specific equipment selection, as it as learning to see, carefully selecting settings and lighting, and so on - in other words, learning to be a photographer, rather than having specific gear.

Comment: The way the images at the link look have almost nothing to do with what kind of camera was used and almost everything to do with with how the photographer sees lighting and composition. It's not about the gear, it's (almost always) about the scene, the light, and the photographer.

Comment: Related question: [Does the camera matter?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/101665)

Comment: I don't see the point on downvoting this question. It might be stupid from an expert's POV but almost all of us we've been there. Just encourage the guy to focus on the technique rather than the gear. And by the way, the photographer makes the photos, but a photographer with an equipment wich is confortable with will make things always easier.

Answer (score 2):

[Robbie Lawrence](http://robbie-lawrence.com/) has likely used multiple cameras and lenses. Based on the Exif info in some photographs, equipment used includes:

- Canon EOS 5D Mark II
- Canon EF 50/1.4 USM
- Adobe Photoshop and Lightroom
- Macintosh

Other pages associated with Robbie Lawrence:

- Freunde von Freunden: [Robbie Lawrence](http://www.freundevonfreunden.com/journal/meet-the-fvf-contributors-robbie-lawrence/)
- Instagram: [robbiel1](https://www.instagram.com/robbiel1/)

Comment: I searched high and low for an interview with him that might have asked about or mentioned his gear. And I found it refreshing that I couldn't find a trace of it, or any sort of brand-ambassadorship-type mentions or nods. Truly, good art, good artist, and the gear doesn't matter. Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I love Robbie's work, so I researched a bit about his gear as well. As someone commented, it could have been any gear! His photography is about narrative as well as aesthetics that light and colors create. He uses all of it to communicate.

That said, here are some of my observations

- Highlights are well controlled, usually underexposed.
- Looks for warm light, oranges and yellows.
- He uses Canon 5D Mark IV, mostly with 70-200 f2.8 lens. He has used Sigma 50 1.4 in the past. I think a telephoto gives him quick access to far away subjects and tight compositions.
- Meters in Spot, Center and Multi depending on lighting conditions and the subject.
- He probably likes film look, uses Lightroom to process, perhaps with some outdated film emulation presets. I don't think he spends a lot of time tweaking in post.

So, his technique is pretty straightforward - A FF DSLR, one telephoto lens and some Lightroom. Rest is his mind, hope this is helps!